# Can I delete install.res.____.dll fies?

Tags: dll

In my main C directory, I have many files which I have no use for and I want to delete them. The thing is, I don't know if it's safe to delete them. I will upload a screen-shot showing the files.

[image: here are the files]

Comment: *main C directory*...you mean the root of C:, correct?

Comment: These files belong to a program which you installed into that directory.  Run the installer and remove the application

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `Yes`.

The VC_RED file (or vc_red file) is a harmless and vital file associated with the VC_RED program. Basically it's a library `(correct me if i get it wrong)`, which needed if you `installing` a program.

However if you want to delete those files, it is completely `safe` because simply, they are *installation files*, not the actual program.

P.S. It's up to you to delete it or not, since in my opinion they doesn't take space that much.

Comment: `vital` means "absolutely essential", making your answer a bit confusing.

Comment: Pardon, `vital` at this state means its important at installing something (since it's the installer). As i mentioned above, those `are not` the program. Only installer, it will automatically created each time you installing `some` program that need vc_red.